# Using Zip to read a file vertically and search through the zipped list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to read a file containing information on different lines - for example the file may contain

```
12345678910
abcdefghij
zyxwvutsrq
```

I will then need to read the code vertically, so my list would be:

```
(1az)(2by)
```

The code I have so far is

```
# grid is the original file that has been read and put into a list
grid2 = zip(*grid) 
for word in words :
        for charc in grid2 :
            if word in charc :
                wordsFound.append(word )
```

I then run then the `zip(*grid)` through my search function but it just returns the entire words file and not just the words it has found

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I've edited your question to be readable. Please - use the edited version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program prints the columns of its input file:

```
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    rows = input_file.readlines()
rows = zip(*[row.strip() for row in rows])
rows = [''.join(row) for row in rows]
print rows
```

Result, when using OP's data:

```
['1az', '2by', '3cx', '4dw', '5ev', '6fu', '7gt', '8hs', '9ir', '1jq']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call readlines or make any intermediary lists, you just need to transpose the file object, using map to remove the newlines:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    # python2 itertools.izip, itertools.imap 
    print(["".join(r) for r in zip(*map(str.rstrip,f))])
```

Output:

```
['1az', '2by', '3cx', '4dw', '5ev', '6fu', '7gt', '8hs', '9ir', '1jq']
```